# Is rebase and merge the same thing? Why are there 2 different procedures to do one thing?

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, git-rebase

I am new to `git` and I am trying to understand the rebase. For me the merge process is easier to understand since my experience is in `Clearcase`.
So first of all I can not understand if rebase is exactly the same as merge or not. If it is why are there 2 procedures for the same thing?
Also I am reading this part from [git-branching](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing#More-Interesting-Rebases).
It has here:
[image]

Then it says:

> $ git rebase --onto master server client
>   This basically says, “Check
>   out the client branch, figure out the patches from the common
>   ancestor of the client and server branches, and then replay them onto
>   master.” It’s a bit   complex; but the result, shown in Figure 3-32,
>   is pretty cool.

So I assume this command means take all the commits *after* common ancestor of server and client branches **excluding** the common ancestor. So we end up with the next picture.

[image]

Then it says:

> Now you can fast-forward your master branch (see Figure 3-33):
>   $ git checkout master
>   $ git merge client

[image]

This example seems wrong to me.
In the second picture we "move" `C8` and `C9` as result of the `rebase`. Then we merge.
But `C8` comes out of `C3` and `C3` code is not present in the `master` branch.
After the `rebase` though the new `C8` i.e. `C8'` is in front of `master` and actually has the `master` as previous in chain.
But how can this work? If `C8` is dependent on `C3` the `rebase` fails since `C3` is not part of the `branch`.
E.g. if in `C3` there is some function used by the client, it does not exist in `main` branch. So after the `rebase` the `C8'` will have a dependency in the function defined in `C3` that does not exist in `main`. So the code would not compile.
Could anyone help explaining the `rebase` workflow and if what I say about this part of the tutorial in `git-scm` (that it is wrong) is correct?

Comment: Without having read all of the details, to answer the title question: they're definitely not the same thing; 'merge' creates zero or one new commit; 'rebase' can create arbitrarily many new commits by rewriting a branch's history.

Comment: @gcbenison:What you point out as a difference is the difference on how these to procedures *implement* the *same* functionality. Why are both needed to do the same thing? Also I am asking about an example presented about rebase in the `scm` that I think it is wrong

Comment: @Cratylus - The example isn't *technically* wrong, and you're not either. `C3` would not be included (as shown), because it was the common ancestor - i.e. the 'old base' - of the two commits specified. If `C3` had important things, it would be a problem. That said, I've done things like this when I knew that what I was skipping was unwanted. However, I tend to use the 2nd argument as the 'old base' directly. In other words, if I wanted to do what's shown in the examples, I'd use `git rebase --onto master C3 client`. If I wanted to include `C3`, I'd do `git rebase --onto master C2 client`.

Comment: In other words, instead of `git rebase --onto newbase otherbranch currentbranch`, I think of it as `git rebase --onto newbase oldbase currentbranch`.

Answer (score 1):

no it is not the same thing.
rebase will put the rebased branch commits in line after the branch on which you rebase.

The basic merge will create a new commit result of the merge.

**We could say that rebase avoids having too many parallel branches when merges are obvious.
But in case the merge is complicated (working on same files etc) the merge is better.**
This is because when remerging, git recompute the diffs, like

a = b + diff a
c= b + diff c

merge is d = a + c
rebase is cbis = a + diff cbis

and diff c is probably easy to read, 
diff cplus might be complicated

**also there is the fast forward option that tries to merge in line (like rebase) if the diff is simple, and creates a merge if not. This is probably the best for beginners**